# how web Web API in-memory hosting load our controllers classes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I just learn about Web API in-memory hosting right now, It's new stuff for me. I download the Web API self hosting nuget package and just configure the Routing for Web API and reference the Web API project to In Memory hosting project. And everything is working, but I don't know how in-memory can recognize any controller classes in my Web API project. Is there anyone who can explain me about this?

---

```
    private HttpServer _server;
    private string _url = "http://api.mydomain.com/";

    private HttpClient _client;

    public PortalWebApiInMemoryTest()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        _server = new HttpServer(config);
        _client=new HttpClient(_server);
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in Web API for controller probing to occur the assembly having the controllers should be loaded into memory. In your case if your controllers are defined in the same assembly as your in-memory tests, then the assembly would be scanned for all types which implement `System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController`.

If your controllers are defined in an assembly different from your tests, then you might need to do additional stuff to make sure to have that assembly be loaded into memory. One example is to create a custom `IAssembliesResolver` like in the following sample:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/CustomAssemblyResolverSample/ReadMe.txt

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kiran, I think I need to create simple project to create custom IAssembliesResolver in order to get more understanding about it.